# Getting value from modal issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

What i am trying to do is here is, click on an image and a modal box loads, the user will then enter their email, i will use it to store to a .txt file (or put in a database later on)

**Code:**

```
<p><img src="images/img-get-discount.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#optin_modal" alt="Get your discount on <?= htmlspecialchars($this->getTitle()) ?>"></p> 

    <div id="optin_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6>Enter your email and get a discount on <strong><?= htmlspecialchars($this->getTitle()) ?></strong></h6>
                </div>
                <form id="optin_form" method="post" name="contact" role="form">
                    <div class="modal-body">                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="optin_email" name="optin_email" class="form-control">
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">                  
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="I Want The Discount!">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['optin_email'])) {
        echo $_POST['optin_email'];
    }
    ?>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#optin_form").submit(function(event){
              alert($('#optin_email').val());
              return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When the user clicks on the image, the modal loads fine, i seem to be having trouble getting the value at this point: `alert($('#optin_email').val());` it's not alerting out for some reason, have i missed something obvious in the code at all? i'm not the best with jquery.

Comment: I can not reproduce this = its working fine for me and i can see the alert popping up with the email entered. Are you sure you are loading the jQuery scripts on your pages and there are no errors in the browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the form will submit with a browser reload, do this to stop the behavior

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#optin_form").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); // will prevent the browser from submitting your form normally 
            alert($('#optin_email').val());
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is Working Fine. You Can Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/qrmnyvg3/

```
<p><img src="images/img-get-discount.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#optin_modal" alt="Get your discount on <?= htmlspecialchars($this->getTitle()) ?>"></p> 

    <div id="optin_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6>Enter your email and get a discount on <strong><?= htmlspecialchars($this->getTitle()) ?></strong></h6>
                </div>
                <form id="optin_form" method="post" name="contact" role="form">
                    <div class="modal-body">                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="optin_email" name="optin_email" class="form-control">
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">                  
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="I Want The Discount!">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['optin_email'])) {
        echo $_POST['optin_email'];
    }
    ?>
    
    <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#submit").click(function(){
              alert($('#optin_email').val());
              return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thats strange it's not working for me at all in firefox or chrome.

Comment: change #optin_form to #submit in javascript. it will work!